# laravel pick last comment posted related to each post

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have got three tables in laravel like so:

Users, posts, and comments

I'm trying to come up with a query that fetches me all the user's posts, plus the date of last comment with each post.

Approach i've taken that's not working perfectly is:

```
$posts = User::find($userId)->posts()->with('latestComment')->get();
```

In my Post model I have:

```
public function latestComment()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Comment::class)->latest();
}
```

In my findings, i haven't been to see a way to get the date from the lastComment load.

Any pointers welcome,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [eager loading constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads). Code from the other answers will first load all comments, which you don't want.

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', $userId)
             ->with(['comments' => function($q) {
                 $q->taletst()->take(1);
             }])
             ->get();
```

Comment: This will only work when loading a single Post. OP is trying to load many posts.

Comment: @Rob, this will load only one comment per post.

Comment: It will only load one comment, for one post. If you were to try and apply this to many posts, it'd still only load one comment for one of the posts. Every other post would have no comments because you're limiting the comments relationship to 1.

Comment: @Rob I've just tried it and my code works perfectly.

Comment: Your code is wrong for multiple rows. If you want to fetch the latest comment for many posts, it will fetch the relation for the first post only, and comments for all other posts will be nil.

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered one needs to add the foreign key to the select method like so:

```
return $this->hasOne(Comment::class)->latest()->select('field','foreign_key');
```

Comment: This can't be a solution. This code will load all comments data.

Comment: It works, Thanks, we can use * in select to get all columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing relationship and get the latest comment.

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

public function latestComment() {
    return $this->comments()->last();
}
```